# Github Actions workflow : can't change working directory - Error: An error occurred trying to start process '/usr/bin/bash' with working directory

Tags: python, flask, github-actions, working-directory

I want to create a Github workflow to run the tests of my Flask application at each merge request. This is the first time I'm writing one so I'll take any advice.

Here are the content of .github/workflows/test.yml :

```
name: CI
on:
  push:
    branches: [ main, develop ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main, develop ]
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  tests:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python 3.8
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.8
    - name: Install dependencies
      working-directory: fizzbuzz
      run: |
        pwd 
        ls -al
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install -r requirements.txt; 
    - name: Test with pytest
      working-directory: fizzbuzz
      run: |
        python -m pytest
```

However when `pip install -r requirements.txt`, I have : `Error: An error occurred trying to start process '/usr/bin/bash' with working directory '/home/runner/work/fizzbuzz-project/fizzbuzz-project/fizzbuzz'. No such file or directory`

My project is organized this way:

```
├── docker-compose.yml
├── fizzbuzz
│   ├── api
│   │   ├── app.py
│   │   ├── database.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── static
│   │   │   └── swagger.yml
│   │   ├── utils.py
│   │   └── views.py
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── pyproject.toml
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   └── tests
│       ├── test_api.py
│       └── test_utils.py
├── README.md
```

`requirements.txt` is in a subfolder so I tried to specify a working directory but it doesn't seem to work. I find it strange that in the error message `/fizzbuzz-project` is written twice in a row : `'/home/runner/work/fizzbuzz-project/fizzbuzz-project/fizzbuzz'`

`pwd` and `ls -al` don't seem to be displayed :
[Screenshot of the test job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9tbJ.png)

If I don't specify a working directory then I get the error : `ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'`

Do you know where the mistake was in what I did? Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Try running `ls -al` without specifying working directory, and try `pip install -r fizzbuzz/requirements.txt`

Comment: Thank for the reply!
`pwd` returns  `/home/runner/work/fizzbuzz-project/fizzbuzz-project`
and `ls -la` returns :
`drwxr-xr-x 4 runner docker 4096 Apr 29 13:14 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 runner docker 4096 Apr 29 13:14 ..
drwxr-xr-x 8 runner docker 4096 Apr 29 13:14 .git
drwxr-xr-x 3 runner docker 4096 Apr 29 13:14 .github
-rw-r--r-- 1 runner docker   18 Apr 29 13:14 README.md
`
So it seems like there is not my project

Comment: There is no folder `fizzbuzz` on the runner. Are you sure it is part of your repository on GitHub?